# Confused why systemd service doesn't start at boot

Tags: systemd

I have written some simple daemon and I want my system to automatically start it on boot. My daemon needs bluetooth daemon to be started and UNIX socket for outputting data. What is a bit different from what can be read in most manuals and tutorials about systemd is that from daemon point of view I want systemd to create socket for writing, not listening. When I start service and socket manually everything works, however after executing `systemctl enable foo.service` my daemon is not started after reboot. Based on `man systemd.unit`, `man systemd.target` and some googling I have created 3 unit files.

Due to the fact that there seems to be at least few ways in which dependencies can be described for systemd I don't know what is wrong, why my service is not automatically started after reboot. Should I create foo.target file or is it unnecessary in such simple scenario? I am also not sure if `WantedBy` in foo.socket should be set to foo.target or more maybe to sockets.target.

Here is code snippet of my 3 unit files below. I would really appreciate if someone could take a look and give me some tips.

```
############ foo.service file #############################################
[Unit]
Description=Foo Service
Requires=foo.socket

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/start

[Install]
WantedBy=foo.target
###########################################################################
############ foo.socket file ##############################################
[Unit]
Description=Foo socket for write, not for listen

[Socket]
ListenDatagram=/run/foo/foo.sk

[Install]
WantedBy=foo.target
###########################################################################
############ foo.target file ##############################################
[Unit]
Description=Foo target
Requires=bluetooth.target
###########################################################################
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have instructed `systemd` to start your service and socket when your target starts, but you have not instructed the the target should not be started at boot. It has no `[Install]` section-- which is why your service doesn't some up at boot.

A target is not necessary for this simple case.  Move the `Requires=` clause from your target to your service.

For the `WantedBy=` in your service, try using `multi-user.target`, or if your service needs networking, `network-online.target`.

Comment: If I have `Requires=foo.socket` in my foo service unit file, do I also need `WantedBy=foo.service` in foo.socket file in [Install] section? Is the section [Install] needed in foo.socket if it is defined in foo.service that foo.socket is required? Isn't it like writing the same information twice?

Comment: Little fix to previous comment `RequiredBy=foo.service` instead of `WantedBy=foo.service`.

Comment: @AlBundy You are welcome to test removing the `[Install]` section in your socket file. I think you'll find it's unnecessary as you suspect. If my answer was was helpful, please consider upvoting and accepting it. Thanks.